# Pouring liquid out of a bottle smoothly

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, everyday-life

Can one calculate the vacuum pressure created inside a bottle when pouring liquid from it?

Glass bottle
38mm diameter orifice

Answer (score 0):

No vacuum is created. Liquid will not flow out unless air bubble goes inside and equals the atmospheric pressure. (Unless one is taking about a bottle talker than the barometric height, about 1 meter if the liquid is mercury.) The bottle opening does not come into the picture. A wider opening makes it easier for the air bubble to enter.